# MPI_Reduce for array in C

Tags: c, mpi

I have recently started trying to learn MPI to code in C. I am trying to write very small test codes to make sure I know what I'm doing as I go along. Unfortunately, I seem to be having an issue with one of them, which multiplies a matrix with a vector and outputs the resulting vector. Specifically, when I call:

```
MPI_Reduce(c, myc, 3, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

where myc is the part of the vector that is calculated by each processor, my final result is that c[i] = 0 for all i. The code that calculates myc is correct (checked using one processor and outputting myc instead of c). I assume I'm doing something very stupid here, but can't figure out what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want your answer in `c` and not `myc`?

The syntax is:

```
int MPI_Reduce(void *sendbuf, void *recvbuf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, 
           MPI_Op op, int root, MPI_Comm comm)
```

so you are sending `c` into `myc` with your example.

Also note that `recvbuf` is only valid on the root node, which in your case is node 0. All the others will have garbage in `recvbuf`.

Comment: *Sigh*... I really am an idiot. Thanks for pointing out my idiocy. It works now.

Comment: We've all been there, no worries!